# Cacheable method is being invoked when it shouldn't be

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching

I am using Spring Boot 2.7.2 on Java 17.

I have a *ClientImpl* @Component that implements a *Client* interface and that has a *ReportType[] publicReports()* method , it works ok.

```
@Component
public class ClientImpl implements Client {
  @Override public ReportType[] publicReports {...}
}
```

and

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public RestService {
  @Autowired private Client client;
  ...
  @GetMapping(
    path = "reportTypes",
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @RolesAllowed("ROLE_AGNI_BDAC")
  public ResponseEntity<ReportType[]> getPublicReportTypes(
    @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "ca") String language) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(client.publicReports());
  }
}
```

Now, since this method calls a WS to get a master list of types, I want to cache that method invocation. So I have added to my *pom.xml*

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

and modified *ClientImpl*

```
@Component
public class ClientImpl implements Client {
  @Override
  @Cacheable("publicReportTypes")
  public ReportType[] publicReports {...}
}
```

Yet, after that I invoke the WS a couple of times, and each time I see log to the effect that the *publicReports* method is running.

What am I missing?

UPDATE: My *@SpringBootApplication*

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BdacServiceApplication
    implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BdacServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add ‘ @EnableCaching’ on a configuration class?

Comment: Also does your method have argument/s?

Comment: @Mo_- In my initial code the answer to both questions was "no". But I have tried both adding a configuration class (as described here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial) and adding a parameter to the method (an int, to which the calling code always passes "1") and it still does not cache anything.

Comment: He is using Spring Boot so you don't need `@EnableCaching` as that is automatically detected. I suspect you showed dumbed down code as the code included wouldn't even compile. How is the method being called?

Comment: If you are calling the cached method from within the same component where the method is defined, you need to define @Resource member of the same component  and use that to call the method— this might be the issue.

Comment: @M.Deinum I expanded the code to show how it is called. An instance is autowired and then just called from the method. After the modifications made to try Mo_'s suggestion, I just pass an '1' literal as the int parameter.

Comment: @Mo_- No, it is not called from the same component, but from a RestController where the client instance is autowired.

Comment: Could you add your `application.properties` and do you have additional `@Configuration` files (apart from the one you used to add caching?).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it (the diff of the commit). I did try to minimize the changes, so all of the changes have been required.

On the basis of the tutorial I was following I would agree with M.Deinum's comment that *@EnableCaching* was not necessary, but in the end it seems that my setup fails if I do not use it.

Adding a parameter to the method was not necessary.

pom.xml

```
+       <dependency>
+           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
+           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
+       </dependency>
```

ClientImpl.java

```
+ import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;

+   @Cacheable("publicReportTypes")
   @Override
   public ReportType[] publicReports() {
```

CacheConfig.java (new file)

```
+package [REDACTED];
+
+import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
+
+import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
+import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
+import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
+import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
+import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
+import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
+
+import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
+
+@Configuration
+@EnableCaching
+@EnableScheduling
+@Slf4j
+public class CacheConfig {
+
+    @Autowired
+    private CacheManager cacheManager;
+
+    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 30, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MINUTES)
+    public void clearCachePublicReportTypes() {
+        log.info("Clearing cache");
+        this.cacheManager.getCache("publicReportTypes").clear();
+    }
+}
```

Comment: All of that shouldn't be needed. The enable caching is added by default when caching is detected. So this isn't really a fix but rather a workaround.

Comment: @M.Deinum From my reading of the documentation/tutorials, I do agree with you. Yet if I comment *@EnableCaching*, then Spring does not start because it does not find an *org.springframework.cache.CacheManager* bean. I am willing to further research this issue, but I do not know where to look at.

Comment: Something must be disabling the autoconfiguration, do yuo have any excludes on your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class?

Comment: @M.Deinum I have updated the question with my `@SpringBootApplication` class. It is as basic as it gets, I am starting with Spring Boot.